# What is the best way in python to assign each of the same element of one list to the same indices on another list?

Tags: python, list

I thought about having a *word* as a string, making it into a "regularList" of strings, generating a "dummyList" which contains a string '-'for each letter in the *word*, then looping through the "regularList", simultaneously removing each instance of my guessed letter from "regularList" and reassigning it to the same index of "dummyList". Basically, I need to make:

```
regularList = [['a', 'a', 'r', 'd', 'v', 'a', 'r', 'k']]
dummyList = ['_','_','_','_','_','_','_']
```

Into:

```
regularList = [['r', 'd', 'v', 'r', 'k']]
dummyList = ['a','a','_','_','_','a','_','_']
```

Here is my attempt:

```
word = 'aardvark'

def changeLetter(word):
    guess = raw_input('Guess a letter:') # When called, guess:a
    print word
    dummyList = []
    for i in word:
        dummyList.append('_ ')
    print dummyList
    regularList = [list(i) for i in word.split('\n')]
    print regularList
    numIters = 0
    while guess in regularList[0]:
        numIters += 1
        index = regularList[0].index(guess)
        dummyList[index] = guess
        del regularList[0][index]
    print regularList
    print dummyList
    print numIters


changeLetter(word)
```

This code produces:

```
Samuels-MacBook:python amonette$ python gametest.py
Guess a letter:a
aardvark
['_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ']
[['a', 'a', 'r', 'd', 'v', 'a', 'r', 'k']]
[['r', 'd', 'v', 'r', 'k']]
['a', '_ ', '_ ', 'a', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ']
3
```

As you can see, the proper indices aren't being reassigned.

Comment: do not delete your list elements in loop

Comment: Yes I just thought of that! I tried changing "del regularList[0][index]" to      :"regularList[0][index].replace(regularList[0][index],'*h')", just to have the string '*' as a placeholder. This produces an error. Do you know what is wrong with it? Oh yes, then the program will never terminate.

Comment: your loop never end

Answer (score 3):

```
word = 'aardvark'

def changeLetter(word):
    guess = raw_input('Guess a letter:') # When called, guess:a
    print word
    dummyList = []
    for i in word:
        dummyList.append('_ ')
    print dummyList
    regularList = [list(i) for i in word.split('\n')]
    print regularList
    numIters = 0
    position = 0
    length = len(regularList[0])
    while numIters < len(regularList[0]):
        if regularList[0][numIters] == guess:
            dummyList[position] = guess
            del regularList[0][numIters]
            numIters -=1
        position +=1
        numIters +=1
    print regularList
    print dummyList
    print numIters


changeLetter(word)
```

Your program has one mistake when you delete an element the size of array becomes small and the element which should be next becomes previous.

regularList[0] = ['a', 'a', 'r', 'd', 'v', 'a', 'r', 'k']

```
while guess in regularList[0]:
```

In this loop, when you remove first a , list becomes ['a', 'r', 'd', 'v', 'a', 'r', 'k']

Now when your loop continues, guess becomes 'r' that is next element in previous list. Hence a which was previously at  position 1 is neglected (0 based indexing).

Comment: This program works. Excellent. I will study this to learn what I was doing wrong. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with enumerate and then remove the elements:

```
for index, element in enumerate(regularList):
    if element == "a":
        dummyList[index] = element
regularList.remove("a")
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is way too long, you can just use a clean list comprehension

```
currentWord = [letter if letter in guessedLetters else "_" for letter in solution]
```

A fully functioning guess the word program without win logic would be 6 lines

```
solution = "aardvark"
guessedLetters = []
while True:
    guessedLetters.append(input("Guess a letter "))
    currentWord = [letter if letter in guessedLetters else "_" for letter in solution]
    print(" ".join(currentWord))
```

This outputs:

```
Guess a letter a
a a _ _ _ a _ _
Guess a letter k
a a _ _ _ a _ k
Guess a letter v
a a _ _ v a _ k
Guess a letter r
a a r _ v a r k
Guess a letter d
a a r d v a r k
Guess a letter
```